# Raphael.js irregular path around a center point

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, raphael

I have a center point with 18 axes going outward every 20deg.
How do I draw a path from any point along one path to the next, all the way around.
E.g. starts at 20px out from center at 0deg, then draws to 40px out at 20deg, then draws to 100px out at 40deg, etc.

I started going down some paths (sorry) but couldn't find anything in the [documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html) to do what I want (at least not overtly). I thought maybe getPointAtLength would be the answer but couldn't get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build up a string defining the path as described in http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path, which will require some trigonometry. Assuming you have a center point at (cx, cy) and an array of radii:

```
var commands = 'M';
var radii = [20, 40, 100, ...];
var cx = 200;
var cy = 200;

for (var i=0; i<18; i++) {
    var theta = Math.PI * i/9;
    var x = cx + radii[i] * Math.cos(theta);
    var y = cy + radii[i] * Math.sin(theta);
    commands += x + ' ' + y + ' ';
}

var p = paper.path(commands);
```

Comment: Thanks for the mad trig knowledge, Peter. Now to figure out how to center the fill image on cx,cy -- not based on the shape top left. I feel another question being asked soon...

Comment: As you generate x and y keep track of the minimum and maximum values of each, then cx = (max_x - min_x)/2 and likewise for y. That should work.